# Find the area of the entire shape.

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, solution-verification, area

[image]

ABCD is a straight line. ABE is a sector of a circle with center B. CED is a sector of a circle with center C. Angle ABE is a right angle. The length of AB is r and angle ACE is π/4 radians. If r=10cm, find the area of the shape.

Length of $CD= √2 r$, Angle $ECD= 3π/4,$ Area of shape= Area of AEB + Area of EBC + Area of ECD = 25π + 50 + 75π = 364cm^2 (to 3s.f.)

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: Length of CD= √2 r, Angle ECD= 3π/4, Area of shape= Area of AEB + Area of EBC + Area of ECD = 25π + 50 + 75π = 364cm^2 (to 3s.f.)

Comment: If so, you can find an area of the sector ECD, which ends the solution.

Comment: The answer key states that the answer is 325cm^2, so I'm not sure whether its an error or not

Comment: @Anns I think, your solution is right. I got the same result.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, your solution is right.

I got the same result:
$$\frac{\pi r^2}{4}+\frac{r^2}{2}+\frac{3\pi(r\sqrt2)^2}{8}=\left(\pi+\frac{1}{2}\right)r^2=100\pi+50.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**
$\left| \bar{AB}  \right | = \left| \bar{BE}  \right |, \\
\sin\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\left| \bar{BE}  \right |}{\left| \bar{CE}  \right |}, \\
 \left| \bar{CE}  \right | = \left| \bar{CD}  \right |, \\
\left| \bar{BC}  \right |^2 = \left| \bar{CE}  \right |^2 - \left| \bar{BE}  \right |^2.$